# Writing a Google Analytics-like Javascript code to capture current URL and send it back to a server 

Tags: javascript

I would like to give out js code for people to put on their site. Once the code is on their site, I would like to capture the url of the current page. How can I do this ?

For example, I would like to mimic the google Adwords model but I will not be serving ads.

I just want to capture the url's of the pages in which my code is being used.

Comment: You'll need a server-side language too, because you can't pass information between different people (or collect information) with just JavaScript.

Comment: Yes but do you know how I can read the js an write the js to be consumed by the other site  im using php   any tutorials youve seen?

Comment: capture the url with javascript and make a request to your server with the captured url in the querystring

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/build-live-visitor-tracking-system/) will help. It isn't the exact thing that you want, but maybe it will help you get started with it. It uses PHP and JavaScript.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i think i got the php down. i just need to know how to write js for the other site and to consume or talk to the js on the other site to capture the url

Comment: @RafaelDaCosta - Maybe you could have a hidden a iframe on the page and when you view the page the iframe (which would be your PHP page that counts views for each different site) would count that as a view and if you don't want each view to be counted as a view, you could set a cookie to make sure that same visitor doesn't get counted. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I just want to get their url with javascript i provide to them.   similar to what google does w/ ad words     <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "id";
google_ad_slot = "9196566825";
google_ad_width = 234;
google_ad_height = 60;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>

Comment: if i give them an iframe . will the iframe be able to read their urls string?

Comment: in other words, if another site serves <iframe src='http://www.somesite.com/url_capture.php?var=0123456789'  frameborder='0' height='500' width='250' scrolling='no'></iframe>  can I get their url where this code is?

Comment: can you try this?      can you put this on a test page of your site/server?

if so, does it read the url?

<iframe src='http://collectivedashboard.com/facebook/test_url_ping.php'  frameborder='0' height='500' width='250' scrolling='no'></iframe>

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://weebuild.heliohost.org/iframe_test.html I suggest you use JavaScript to put in the iframe so they don't know you're using an iframe (unless they look at the JavaScript file) and so it is a smaller code. (and they won't be able to adjust anything in the iframe) You could do something like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://someurl.com/thejavascript.js.php?var=0123456789"></script>`

Comment: however, i don't think it will read your url (http://weebuild.heliohost.org/iframe_test.html) since it's an iframe it only it only reads my url. this is my challenge, i think i can only do this with js but i don't know how

Comment: I see that it isn't working. What you could do is use JavaScript to get the page URL from the iframe with something like: `parent.window.location` which would show `weebuild.heliohost.org/iframe_test.html`. What are you using right now to get the URL?

Comment: just using php. let me try the js you mention

Comment: i think i got it:  var page_my_code_is_on  = (document.referrer);
 document.write(page_my_code_is_on);

Comment: No problem, if this answer helps you could you click the check mark next to it to mark it as accepted? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When the client sends a request message such as GET the webserver will be aware of this request, so can capture it in server logs, or log it your self when they request a specific file such as php you could set the `header` as `application/javascript` and preform logging then such as adding it to a database which you could use `REQUEST_URI` to capture the uri

Comment: david  do you have any example or seen any on the web.

Comment: i think i got it : var page_my_code_is_on  = (document.referrer);
 document.write(page_my_code_is_on);